# EditText hint as shared pref default?

Tags: android, android-studio, sharedpreferences

Is it possible to set the EditText "hint" or default text to the value of a sharedpref string? I have 3 EditText, one button, when the button is clicked, the 3 values are saved in SharedPreferences for a later time in the app. As of right now, once the button is clicked the 3 edit texts stay to the values entered, but if you leave the activity and return, they all go back to blank. I'm wondering if there is a way to set them so they are the sharedpref value of the string, and if nothing is saved set them to the default given. Also, how do I set the default value of a sharedpref String? Thanks!

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
            if (mEditTextBench.getText().length() > 0 && mEditTextDead.getText().length() > 0 && mEditTextSquat.getText().length() > 0) {
                editor.putString("maxDead", mEditTextDead.getText().toString());
                editor.putString("maxSquat", mEditTextSquat.getText().toString());
                editor.putString("maxBench", mEditTextBench.getText().toString());
                editor.apply();
```

This is my code in another layout to test to make sure it is properly saving.(which it is) I'm not entirely sure what the "null" is doing though. So if anyone can help with that too thanks!!

```
String maxDead = pref.getString("maxDead", null);
    TextView textViewTest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTest);
    textViewTest.setText(maxDead);
```

Answer (score 1):

Doh!! Figured it out! Added this to onCreate:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
    String maxDeadHint = pref.getString("maxDead", "100");
    mEditTextDead.setHint(maxDeadHint);
```

My bad! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Once you make the appropriate replacements, this should work:

```
TextView deadText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.//insert id//);
TextView squatText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.//insert id//);
TextView benchText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.//insert id//);

deadText.setHint(pref.getString("maxDead", "default_value"));
squatText.setHint(pref.getString("maxSquat", "default_value"));
benchText.setHint(pref.getString("maxBench", "default_value"));
```